# How to minimize all windows except the selected ones?

Tags: finder, mission-control

Ok, if you use <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> you can hide all windows except the active one.

How can I minimize (or hide) all windows except a set of 3 or 4 windows chosen by the user? Is there any app for that?

Comment: `⌥ALT`+`⌘CMD`+`H` does not minimize the windows - it hides them. Minimized windows are visible on the Dock. Hidden windows are not.

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek Note that this is dependent on a system preferences setting. It can be set such that minimized windows minimize into their respective Dock icon and not as a separate window on the right of the Dock.

Comment: @BartArondson You're right, but this is still minimized state. Hidden =/= Minimized.

Comment: Yes, you are right. However, when they minimize to the Dock icon it is nearly the same AFAIK.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the most accepted term, Minimize or Hide. Someone edited the question already, thanks.